# LWJGL view opens twice or something

Tags: java, swing, lwjgl

I've managed to get lwjgl working on a canvas inside swing, however when i open the application, the lwjgl opens briefly another window named 'Source'.

It is not really a problem since it all works afterwards, but it bothers me and i want to fix it.

I am not even sure of what's happening actually, here is a gif of what happens

[image]

The code on the gif is actually from another example where it works as intended

Here is the relevant opengl code, everything else on this project is swing component instancing

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                addLibraryPath("./lib/");
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Display.create();
                Display.setParent(canvas);
                GL11.glViewport(0, 0, 195, 195);
            } catch (LWJGLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            GL11.glClearColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            Display.update();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really embarrassing, since i found out what the problem as about 2 minutes after posting the question

I just had to swap

```
Display.create();
Display.setParent(canvas);
```

making it

```
Display.setParent(canvas);
Display.create();
```

I hope this somehow help someone